# ATtiny85 auto resets when switching MOSFET with load

Tags: mosfet, current, attiny85

I'm currently designing a simple circuit to act as a remote firework igniter. I'm using the ATtiny85 to control a MOSFET as a switch which would connect a coil of nichrome wire to the battery terminals and make it really hot to ignite the firework.

The problem is that when I switch the MOSFET and the load is connected, the microcontroller auto resets. I am using the switch connected to pin 3 as an input pull-up, and every time the button is pressed I programmed the ATtiny to turn on and off the MOSFET gate 2 times with a 1 s delay inbetween to make sure the nichrome gets enough time to heat up. The other LEDs are just indicators showing that the ATtiny is on and when the gate of the MOSFET is turned on.

My problem is that when the load is connected the microcontroller auto resets. I think it has something to do with the high current drawn from the battery, but I would like to hear any recommendations as to how I could solve this problem. I was thinking of adding a decoupling capacitor across VCC and GND, but I don't know if this will solve the issue. Any insight as to how I could improve this circuit would be highly aprecciated.

[image: Circuit I built]

[image]

Comment: If you've been thinking about using a decoupling capacitor, why haven't you tried it yet? In general, you should not operate a microcontroller without a decoupling capacitor.

Comment: I don't think a decoupling cap will help much. If the voltage from battery drops under the load so much that MCU resets; then the battery simply can't provide enough current to the load.

Comment: grab the datasheet for the ATTINY85 and give the VCC and RST pins the recommended treatment.

Comment: What would the recommended pins treatment would be? Also I tried using a bench power supply which can provide much more current but I still get the same behavior and I tried connecting a 10uF cap across Vcc and Gnd but is still autoreseting

Comment: Would you mind showing us a picture of your physical circuit?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the post I used pin headers for easy access to the ATtiny pins in case I need to program it, also in the picture de yellow cable is connected to the drain of the MOSFET, and the black one to the source, here's where I connect my load, directly from the +4.2V from the battery and the negative lead gets switched by the MOSFET, I also tried using an old computer power supply that can supply up to 22 A on the +5V line but I still get the same behavior the ATtiny auto resets is there anything wrong with this circuit? any advice would be highly aprecciated

Comment: You may be triggering the brown-out detector. See 8.2.3 in the datasheet.

Comment: Those wires look suspiciously thin for carrying multiple amps of current (potentially 5A or more), and the power switch likely can't handle it either... It'd be nice if you could measure the supply voltage right at the microcontroller's pins while the MOSFET is on and powering the nichrome wire. It's likely dropping too low. To simulate the MOSFET being on permanently, you can bridge its drain and source terminals with a bit of solder. If you have an oscilloscope, use that to measure the voltage drop when pressing the button.

Comment: Yes, thank you I believe this is what is causing the problem " The brown-out detector is designed to put the chip into reset when the voltage gets too low, and hold it in reset until the voltage returns back to a safe operating level."

Comment: since I'm powering the chip from the same battery as the load, the drop in VCC due to the load is too much that it triggers this, now the question how could I solve this? I still want to use the same battery to power this, do you think a voltage regulator on the Vcc and Gnd of the MCU would do it? if not is there another solution I could use for this? should I disable the BOH detector on the ATtiny? I look forward to your reply thanks!

Comment: `tried using a bench [PS] […] tried connecting a 10uF cap across Vcc and Gnd` Please prefer augmenting the post body over commenting comments - this is not chat. Has the cap been close to the ATtiny? Did doing both simultaneously not help?

Comment: How old is that battery? The ESR may be getting high if it’s seen a lot of action

Comment: Have you tried to measure the voltage between VDD and GND (at the pins of ATtiny) when powering on the load? With a scope preferably since it can be a short transient.

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some resistance in series with your line from pin 4 to the gate, say 50 or 100 ohms, since the gate will draw a lot of current due to the gate charge needed to turn on the FET.

Comment: It's a silly question but do you even need the ATtiny? Seems like you could directly control the MOSFET, or even directly control the coil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your schematic you basically short circuit your supply voltage when you switch the MOSFet on.

As others noted the supply voltage likely drops enough to send your microcontroller into a brownout condition.
Several things probably work against you here:

- Static voltage drop: the internal resistance of the battery and the battery wires lead to a voltage drop while the load is connected.
- Transient voltage drop: There are no buffer or decoupling caps. When the switch is turned on the voltage drops immediately on the board and the long wires (inductance) to your battery lead to lagging response.
  This is likely the bigger factor in this setup and can be enough to reset your controller or get other odd behavior.

An easy solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOimVD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Split the power supply by using a diode. Behind the diode connect a large buffer capacitor (hundreds of uF). To this supply you only connect your controller.

When you turn on the MOSFet, your Microcontroller supply is now buffered and the load can not draw from this buffer. But as long as the load is active, your buffer will not charge up again, so the buffer needs to be large enough. It only has to buffer the MCU and the LEDs. I recommend increasing the series resistors for the LEDs to reduce the loading on your buffer.
I prefer this over just adding decoupling caps as it will be more robust. Adding a decoupling capacitor close to the IC is still recommended though.

Additionaly you could add a large buffer capacitor bank on the output of your battery to reduce the load on your battery. But for this a lot more energy has to be stored and you would need a soft start circuit for slow charging to get a net benefit.